# CSS HTML hiding a field from screen's right

Tags: html, css, forms, styles

I positioned a form to the right of a document showing only a part of it

```
<form class="right-form">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
</form>
```

and I styled like this(simplified example)

```
 body{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }

.right-form{
   position:absolute;
   rigth: -220px;
   width: 250px
   transition: width 0.5s ease 0s, right 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.right-form:hover{
   right: 0px;
}
```

Everything works well except the scroll bar at the bottom appears to scroll left to the right when the form is hidden, and I do not want it to appear. Someone knows how to deal with this css problem? Hope the problem is understandable...

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
    with the overflow rule proposed by matthias.p the user can still press the arrow key pad a scroll to the right

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the body rule.

**Edit:**
You could do this:

```
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.right-form {
position:absolute;  
right: 0;
width: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
.right-form:hover {
width: 250px;
}
```

Instead of changing the `right` value I have changed the width of the form and did the `overflow` on the form instead on the body. Now you cannot use the arrow keys anymore to display the form when not hovering.

Comment: Thanks a lot but with the arrow pad you can still go to the right or left and see the mess..do you have something for this?

Comment: Thanks a lot... I found you can also kill the usage of the arrow keys with javascipt. that is a different way to do so eventhough you see the form contracted... you won a extra point anyway

Answer (score 0):

Usage of overflow does still allow the usage of arrow keys..
You can kill the usage of arrow keys like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
     switch(event.keyCode){
        case 37:
        case 39:
            return false;
            break;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, the 100% + the default margin is causing the issue

```
body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.right-form{
     position:absolute;
     rigth: -220px;
     width: 250px
     transition: width 0.5s ease 0s, right 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.right-form:hover{
     right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Well I actually use the margin:0px and padding:0px in my real webpage, but thanks anyways.