# Activating and deactivating arrow keys with jquery

Tags: jquery, textarea, onfocus

I am deactivating the left and right arrow keys when the page is loaded with the following:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
     switch(event.keyCode){
        case 37:
        case 39:
            return false;
            break;
     }
 });
```

I want to reactivate them when the textarea or a input field id onfocus, and deactivate them again when that element is not in focus anymore. How would you do that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to disable arrow keys?

Comment: I had a css problem and I did not find a solution here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968779/css-html-hiding-a-field-from-screens-right/11969556#11969556 I could not find a better way than deactivating the arrow keys.

Comment: That's... that's like cutting off your arm because you can't find nail clippers.

Comment: I know that.. I am pretty aware that a css solution is way better. But I don't have the solution. If you have one let me know..

Comment: Shouldn't you post a question about how to make the CSS solution to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the `event.target`.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement 
     || event.target instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement)     { 
       return true;
    }
     switch(event.keyCode){
        case 37:
        case 39:
            return false;
            break;
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks I guess this is common jquery knowledge which I don't have... thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.. but you really shouldn't do this for accessiblity reasons.

```
var blockKeys = true; //Set this to true or false as needed
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
     switch(event.keyCode){
        case 37:
        case 39:
            if(blockKeys === true) {
                event.PreventDefault();
            }
            break;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this as your condition to return in the switch case

```
if(event.target.tagName != "INPUT" &&  event.target.tagName != "TEXTAREA" )
{
   return false;
   break;
  }
```